# Neural Network Reduction - pruning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

**Context**

I am currently working on an assignment, in the reference paper given by the assignment it has mentioned a technique using to reduce network topology (the size of hidden layer).

**Technique**

Suppose we have a feed-forward network, and there's one hidden layers with weight `W1`. Considering `W1` might initialized bigger than we need, we want to prune it. The pruning is based on 2 principles:

1. shut down one of two units that are too similar (two vectors in `W1` with angle less than degree of 15)
2. shut down complementary units both of them (two vectors in `W1` with angle larger than degree of 165)

I understand the first principle, in backpropgation, hidden units with the same weights are likely to update by the same amount, so no need to keep 2 same hidden units (also you can check [this video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks-deep-learning/lecture/XtFPI/random-initialization) from Andrew Ng deep learning course).

**Question**

But for the second principal, the paper itself didn't give any explanation and I cannot find any evidence to convince myself. Why do such removal?

Comment: I think they/you mean that the *absolute* difference of the angles (and then somewhat modulo 180) must be < 15 or > 165 degrees. Let’s assume that the difference of angles is exactly 180 degrees. That means that the weight vector of one of the units is minus the weight vector of the other one. Assuming that you do not use an activation function then the first unit predicts the same as the second one (up to the minus sign). Hence they are similar as well...?

Comment: This sounds like a fairly old NN regularization technique, and not in common usage. Modern methods don't focus on pruning the individual nodes, so much as training the nodes to operate independently (e.g. dropout).